# How do I input My FIle?

Tags: java, android, development-environment, mode

I have dug around and found a function to copy files, my only issue is I do not know where I insert my directory (I'm moving `"/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db"` to `"/sdcard/tpzb/"`)

I would appreciate some help very much. All I need is someone to put `"FILE TO COPY DIR"` and `"OUTPUT DIR"` in where it goes. I know this is a dumb question but I see many other functions like this, I figure once I see one I will be able to figure it out on my own with out asking. :)

```
private void moveFile(String inputPath, String inputFile, String outputPath) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }


        in = new FileInputStream(inputPath + inputFile);        
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + inputFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;

            // write the output file
            out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        new File(inputPath + inputFile).delete();  


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [code](http://pastie.org/10334900) to copy file

also, don't forget to add below permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Usage

```
copyFile("/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/tpzb/");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just do not understand what the Usage is? Where do I Implement this?

Comment: you can implement this as per your requirement, like inside onCreate() or inside button click

Comment: Ok, I have done this and now the problem is The app force closes when I click the button.

Comment: can you post your code? and also make sure that your are copying files to sdcard inside your application package only

Comment: I will tommrow. I am going to see if it is my headers or if it's in the body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85383/discussion-between-durgesh-patel-and-display-word).